# Как в laravel изменить значение одного поля?

Tags: laravel

как уменьшить значение одного поле на единицу ?

```
    $user = User::find(1);
    $post = $user->post->where('active', 1);

    if(post == 1){
       // Обновить одно поле в записи на единицу, к примеру поле class = 84, если попадаем сюда то значение уменьшаем на 1, получится class = 83 и сохраняем в базе
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Laravel есть возможность для решения этой задачи. Можете читать [здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#increment-and-decrement)

**Пример:**

С использование фасада `DB`:

```
// Увеличивается значение поля на единицу
DB::table('users')->increment('class');

// Увеличивается значение поля на 5
DB::table('users')->increment('class', 5);

// Уменьшается значение поля на единицу
DB::table('users')->decrement('class');

// Уменьшается значение поля на 5
DB::table('users')->decrement('class', 5);
```

С использование **моделей** таблиц:

```
// Увеличивается значение поля
User::find(1)->increment('class');
User::find(1)->increment('class', 5);

// Уменьшается значение поля
User::find(1)->decrement('class');
User::find(1)->decrement('class', 5);
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал...